# Javascript objects can have more than one method, right?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to really understand the javascript language. I am learning the differences between functions and methods.

This answer explains that methods are functions attached to objects: [Difference between a method and a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

But [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) article from MDN says that

> A value of property can be a function, which is then known as the
>   object's method.

The sentence from MDN implies that JS objects have single methods. Is that correct? In other words: can javascript objects have multiple methods? Or is there a javascript concept roughly akin to "The Object's Method."

Comment: How about you try it? Side note: there is no real difference between a function and a method in JavaScript.

Comment: You seem ultra focused on that one sentence. Read the entire article, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @freakish a method can use the word this and it would refer to the objects context. If a function uses the word this, it refers to Object. Right?

Comment: @akh2103 Not quite. If you have a function `fn` and an object `x` and you will do `fn.call(x);` then `this` becomes `x` (it doesn't matter whether `fn` is a method or a function). And that's what happens under the hood: `x.fn()` is equivalent to `fn.call(x)`. So there is no much difference.

Comment: @akh2103 Also if you have a function `fn` and you call it directly: `fn()` then `this` becomes `window`, i.e. `fn()` is equivalent to `fn.call(window)`. Read more about *call* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and about its sister function *apply* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript objects can certainly have multiple methods.**

I find the [quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) less confusing if we preserve the original italics:

> A value of property can be a function, which is then known as the object's *method*.

The "the" goes with "object", not "method".

Comment: Probably would be less confusing if the quote was "... then known as AN object's method." For that matter, they could have left "object's" out altogether.

Answer (score 1):

An object can have multiple attributes. Those attributes can contain functions. Functions are also objects, so they in turn also can have multiple attributes and so on.

Comment: Function constructors return Objects, but Functions are not Objects: each are distinct types in the JavaScript type system.

Comment: It's like saying that String class is not a class, it is String (in Java for example), but it is still a class. [A function created with the `function` statement is a `Function object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Description)

Comment: I was being overly simplistic: you are absolutely correct, Functions ARE Objects. They inherit from Function.prototype, which is why we have apply, call, bind, etc. If, however, you do a typeof over a function, the value will be "function", not "Object".

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects can have multiple methods, I think whoever wrote that article just worded it incorrectly, or a little ambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

It can have multiple methods. But it can only have one value at a time. But you could even have multiple methods that each return the value...

Answer (score 0):

JS objects can have multiple methods like

- window.alert("");
- window.confirm("");
- window.prompt("");